# Accept facebook login into my REST API

Tags: facebook, rest, spring-security, token, spring-security-oauth2

I have a backend server (Java / Spring / Spring Security). 
Currently when users from mobile app login, they simply submit their username/password and Spring Security creates a Session and assign it to the request with a JSESSIONID.

We would now also have a button on the mobile app "Login with Facebook". Here is my understanding of how it will work.

1. mobile app uses facebook SDK to get an "access_token"
2. mobile app retrive USer Profile from facebook (name,surname,email etc..)
3. mobile checks (against MY server) if the username is unique
4. If username unique, call MY REST api, with something like this /login/facebook POST over SSL and passing the access_token, email, username etc...)
5. my server then checks if the access_token is valid

   `GET graph.facebook.com/debug_token?
        input_token={token-to-inspect}
        &access_token={app-token-or-admin-token}`
6. If yes, if the UID returned by facebook is already present in my local database, I signin the user as follow:

```java
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null, ROLE_USER));
```

7. If i don't find the UID, I just create a new user and login the user.
8. and from now on every request made to the server by the mobile will have the SESSION (created and attached by spring security) and the mobile app is authenticated

Could someone tell me if this is a good way of doing things ?
Should I stop using sessions and switch to Spring-Security-OAUTH2 ?

---

**EDIT 1**

Based on Dave advices here is the updated spring-security config:

```
    <!- handle login by providing a token-->
    <security:http pattern="/login/facebook" auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
                <security:custom-filter ref="facebookLoginFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
                <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    </security:http>


    <bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
                <constructor-arg value="/login/facebook"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <!-- handle basic username + password logins-->
    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="forbiddenEntryPoint">
                <security:form-login login-processing-url="/security_check" authentication-failure-handler-ref="authFailureHandler"
                                     default-target-url="/" always-use-default-target="true" authentication-success-handler-ref="authSuccessHandler" />
                ...
                my others patterns..
                ...

        </security:http>
<bean id="forbiddenEntryPoint"
                class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint" />

            <bean id="authSuccessHandler" class="my.package.AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl"/>
            <bean id="authFailureHandler" class="my.package.AuthenticationFailureHandlerImpl"/>

            <bean id="facebookLoginFilter" class="pl.jcommerce.ocean.web.ws.controller.FacebookLoginFilter">
                <property name="requiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher" ref="loginRequestUrlHandler"></property>
                <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authManager"></property>
            </bean>

            <security:authentication-manager id="authManager">
                <security:authentication-provider ref="facebookAuthenticationProvider" />
            </security:authentication-manager>

            <security:authentication-manager>
                <security:authentication-provider ref="webServiceUserAuthenticationProvider" />
            </security:authentication-manager>

            <bean id="loginRequestUrlHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RegexRequestMatcher">
                <constructor-arg index="0" value="/login/facebook" />
                <constructor-arg index="1" value="POST" />
                <constructor-arg index="2" value="false" />
            </bean>
```

Comment: A Spring Filter is implemented for this purpose. Please see the following link : 

"Spring Authentication Filter for Stateless REST Endpoints which use Facebook Token for authentication"

https://github.com/ozgengunay/FBSpringSocialRESTAuth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook is already using OAuth2 server side, and provides its own native SDK for clients, so I don't see any advantage in your case of using OAuth2 in your server as well, unless your use case extends beyond what you outline above. Spring OAuth2 also has client side support, but not in a native app, so I don't really see anything at all wrong in principle with your proposal. You didn't say in any detail where you would set the security context up in your server, and I think that might be an important detail -- it has to happen in the security filter chain in the right place to get the session to be updated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I thought that using Oauth2 was gonna be easier to integrate the facebook login. Just an idea where I would had a chance to make the migration from session based to token. Regarding where I would authenticate the user, well this is something I *really* wasn't sure where to put it.. Could you point me in more detail to where it has to sit in the filters ?

Comment: If I were you I would look at the implementation of `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` and adapt it to deal with different credentials (fb token instead of username/password). You can then add the filter using `addFilterAfter` in the same position as the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`.

Comment: perfect thank you! This is what I have done: Create a class that extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter and override the "attemptAuthentication" method. I do some basic check and create an Authentication object with the token as principal. I have then created this bean in my config and I have passed it in a new authenticationProvider (that will handle the token verification by contacting facebook graph tools if everything goes well i authenticate the user). and finally I have then created a new "<security:http" in my config with a custom entry point (/login/facebook). DO you approve?

Comment: Sounds good (apart from the XML bit, but that's your funeral).

Comment: A Spring Filter is implemented for this purpose. Please see the following link : 

"Spring Authentication Filter for Stateless REST Endpoints which use Facebook Token for authentication"

https://github.com/ozgengunay/FBSpringSocialRESTAuth

Answer (score 0):

I took a crack at implementing something like this based on Dave Syer's answer here along with the Spring Security Angular materials he put together. To see an example see my [forked](https://github.com/alex94115/spring-security-angular) github repo, specifically the classes in the [security](https://github.com/alex94115/spring-security-angular/tree/master/proxy/ui/src/main/java/demo/security) package.